# I keep getting a nullpointer exception error when checking for a boolean

Tags: java

In BlueJ and Eclipse I get a nullpointer exception when checking for String-equality.

Here's my code:

```
import java.util.Set;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Iterator;

/**
 * Class Room - a room in an adventure game.
 *
 * This class is part of the "World of Zuul" application. 
 * "World of Zuul" is a very simple, text based adventure game.  
 *
 * A "Room" represents one location in the scenery of the game.  It is 
 * connected to other rooms via exits.  For each existing exit, the room 
 * stores a reference to the neighboring room.
 *
 * @author  Michael Kölling and David J. Barnes
 * @version 2016.02.29
 */

public class Room
{
    private String description;
    private String itemDescription;
    private HashMap<String, Room> exits;        // stores exits of this room.
    private ArrayList<Item> items;

    /**
     * Create a room described "description". Initially, it has
     * no exits. "description" is something like "a kitchen" or
     * "an open court yard".
     * @param description The room's description.
     */
    public Room(String description)
    {
        this.description = description;
        this.itemDescription = "This room contains: ";
        exits = new HashMap<>();
        items = new ArrayList<Item>();
    }

    public Room(String description, Item item)
    {
        items = new ArrayList<Item>();
        this.description = description;
        addItem(item);
        this.itemDescription = "This room contains: " + item.getLongDescription() ;
        exits = new HashMap<>();
    }
    /**
     * Define an exit from this room.
     * @param direction The direction of the exit.
     * @param neighbor  The room to which the exit leads.
     */
    public void setExit(String direction, Room neighbor)
    {
        exits.put(direction, neighbor);
    }

    public void addItem(Item item)
    {
        items.add(item);
        System.out.println(itemDescription.equals("This room contains: "));
        this.itemDescription = this.itemDescription + /*(this.itemDescription.equals("This room contains: ") ?
        "" : ", ")*/ ", " + item.getLongDescription();
    }

    public void removeItem(String shortItemDescription){
        int i= 0;
        Iterator<Item> it = items.iterator();
        while(it.hasNext()){
            if (it.next().getShortDescription().equals(shortItemDescription)){
                it.remove();
                i++;
            }
            else
                i++;
        }
    }

    public  ArrayList<Item> getItems(){
        return items;
    }

    /**
     * @return The short description of the room
     * (the one that was defined in the constructor).
     */
    public String getShortDescription()
    {
        return description;
    }

    /**
     * Return a description of the room in the form:
     *     You are in the kitchen.
     *     Exits: north west
     * @return A long description of this room
     */
    public String getLongDescription()
    {
        return "You are " + description + ".\n" + (itemDescription.equals("This room contains: ") ?
                "This room is empty" : itemDescription) + ".\n" + getExitString();
    }

    /**
     * Return a string describing the room's exits, for example
     * "Exits: north west".
     * @return Details of the room's exits.
     */
    private String getExitString()
    {
        String returnString = "Exits:";
        Set<String> keys = exits.keySet();
        for(String exit : keys) {
            returnString += " " + exit;
        }
        return returnString;
    }

    /**
     * Return the room that is reached if we go from this room in direction
     * "direction". If there is no room in that direction, return null.
     * @param direction The exit's direction.
     * @return The room in the given direction.
     */
    public Room getExit(String direction)
    {
        return exits.get(direction);
    }
}
```

In the method `addItem(Item item)` I get a nullpointer exception error when checking for the String comparison-method `itemDescription.equals("This room contains: ")`, as well as in the `System.out.println()`-statement as in the outcommented ternary operator-test for `itemDescription.equals("This room contains: ")`.

The strange thing is that the ternary operator in `getLongDescription()` functions fine.

Comment: Use a debugger. Put a breakpoint on the line that fails. Check each of the references to see which is null.

Comment: `getLongDescription` is on a `item`, the exception is on `itemDescription` so there is "nothing" strange about this, those two are not related. Unless you need a value from that `item` .... `itemDescription` doesn't seems to be null (since instanciate in both constructor) but you need to debug this yourself or propose a [mcve].

Comment: Please check the order of instructions in your constructors. At least in one of them the method `addItem` is called before `this.itemDescription` is initialized

Comment: Thanks a lot Stefan Freitag. That solved my problem completely!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you build a `Room` instance with an `Item`. You call `addItem` before instantiating the `itemDescription` variable.

```
public Room(String description, Item item) 
{
    // ...
    addItem(item);
    this.itemDescription = "This room contains: " + item.getLongDescription() ;
    // ...
}
```

So in the method `addItem`, `this.itemDescription` is still null.

```
public void addItem(Item item)
{
    // ...
    System.out.println(itemDescription.equals("This room contains: ")); 
    // ...
}
```

And this breaks.

To correct the problem, call `addItem` after you instanciate `itemDescription`. Note that you don't need to add the `item` description since this is already done in the `addItem` method.

```
public Room(String description, Item item) 
{
    // ...
    this.itemDescription = "This room contains: ";
    addItem(item);
    // ...
}
```

---

You are going to regret that `String itemDescription` really fast !

Instead, create  method `getRoomDescription` that will iterate the `items` list and generate that `String itemDescription` (using a `StringBuilder`) !

Something like

```
public String getRoomDescription(){
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder("Rooms contains :");
    for(Item i : items){
         sb.append("\n".append(i.getLongDescription());
    }
    return sb.toString();
}
```

Editing the `itemDescription` variable is messy and is prone to problem (like you have encountered).

---

Last thing, the test you do with

```
itemDescription.equals("This room contains: ")
```

Should give you the same result as

```
items.size() == 0
```

But is easier to understand (no value in `items` list) and is less prone to mistake if you edit the way you want to print the description.

Comment: This question is still a duplicate, but I had to mention the last part. The alternative is more interesting, cleaner and easier to maintain !

Comment: And you, too. Thanks a lot for the in-depth commenting.